# RXJS - How to subscribe multiple times

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have a service getCompanies that returns me an object with an array called "roles".
I need to call a service using each string into the array as parameter. I need to invoke the service and subscribe as many times as the elements into the array are...

```
getCompaniesByRole() {
  let role: string;
 
  this.sidebarService
  .getCompanies(userId)
  .pipe(
    map(companiesList => {
      // dispatch ngrx action
      return companiesList.roles //array of strings
    }),
    switchMap(roles => {
      roles.forEach(el => {
        role = el;
        return this.getFileService(el); // it gives me an error, I want to invoke the service here and subscribe for doing some logic; and come back here if there are others elements in the "roles" array.
      };
    })

  ).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(role);
    console.log(res);
  })
}
```

Comment: Did either of these answers help?

Answer (score 0):

[`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) will help you out.  It will create a single observable, from an array of observables and emit once all have completed.

So, you can map your roles to `this.getFileService()`, which would be an array of observables.  Then just wrap that in `forkJoin` inside your switchMap:

```
this.sidebarService.getCompanies(userId)
  .pipe(
    map(companiesList => companiesList.roles),
    switchMap(roles => 
      forkJoin(roles.map(el => this.getFileService(el)))
    )
  );
```

Note: forkJoin will not emit if the source observables do not complete or if ANY of them error out.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot wrong with that code:

You have a `return` statement in an `Array.prototype.forEach` callback but `forEach` ignores any values returned by its callback.

You should be using `Array.prototype.map` to create an array of the Observable results of calling the service with each role string.

You don't need multiple subscriptions, although that's certainly possible with RxJS it makes no sense for this case at all.

Finally, `switchMap` doesn't make sense here because you want to obtain all of the results, not just those of the last service call to complete.

Here's roughly what it should look like

```
getCompaniesByRole() {
   this.sidebarService
    .getCompanies(userId)
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(companiesList => {
        // dispatch ngrx action
        return companiesList.roles //array of strings
      }),
      mergeMap(role => this.getFileService(role))
    })
    .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: I know, sorry!! I write that it gives an error...this was a way to explain what I wanted...